# How to describe product category and product name in Google Tag Manager dataLayer for multilingual website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

There are 3 languages on my site: Swedish, Norwegian and Finnish. Also English language is used as a fallback.

And currently GTM data is different between languages.

For example,
GTM dataLayer for Swedish language:

```
{
    productName: "Swedish product name",
    category: "Swedish category name"
}
```

GTM dataLayer for Norwegian language:

```
{
    productName: "Norwegian product name",
    category: "Norwegian category name"
}
```

GTM dataLayer for Finnish language:

```
{
    productName: "Finnish product name",
    category: "Finnish category name"
}
```

Is the solution above acceptable?
Or GTM data for the same product has to be the same and language independent?

Answer (score 1):

The dataLayer and GTM doesn't care what language you have your product names/categories are in.

Acceptable or not is up to your reporting needs. If those are tracked as some part of an event, they will be categorized separately. Similar if you were doing e-commerce (only sending in the name and category).

I would suggest you do is send product ids and category ids instead. This way the data is language independent, it will be a lot easier to report on as a whole and product name updates/changes won't affect it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct but I would argue that the data you pass into Google Analytics be as human-readable as possible, so my recommendation would be regardless of the user selected language, pass the data in as the language of your teams/analysts.

If/when questions come up around language-based purchases and conversions, you should store a user or session's selected language as a custom dimension so you still have that information. Otherwise you'll be trying to roll things up with regex or mappings, or other nasty work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think you should use an english name for the Product names and Product Categories for all 3 languages so that in your GA reports you will see consistency when viewing the data for a particular product . If in case you want to know on what language the product was viewed then you can send a custom dimension and send the language name ex:"language": "Swedish or Norwegian or Finnish" (the language should be updated dynamically based on what language the user is using)